# I am running my first MapReduce program and there seems to be some permission issue with the output file

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

[mykishore231087@ip-172-31-20-58 ~]$ hadoop jar /usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar \

> -input mayank/data/upx/wc_data.txt \
>   -output /mayank/output/res.txt \
>   -file /home/mykishore231087/d/wordcount_mapper.py \
>   -file /home/mykishore231087/d/wordcount_reducer.py \
>   -mapper "/home/mykishore231087/d/wordcount_mapper.py" \
>   -reducer "/home/mykishore231087/d/wordcount_reducer.py" WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications. 18/04/25 21:28:18 WARN streaming.StreamJob: -file option is deprecated, please use generic option -files instead.
>
> packageJobJar: [/home/mykishore231087/d/wordcount_mapper.py, /home/mykishore231087/d/wordcount_reducer.py] [/usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming
>       -2.7.1.2.3.4.0-3485.jar] /tmp/streamjob8387910308600265451.jar tmpDir=null 18/04/25 21:28:20 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://ip-172-31-13-154.ec2.internal:8188/ws/v1/timeline/ 18/04/25 21:28:20 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-53-48.ec2.internal/172.31.53.48:8050 18/04/25 21:28:21 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://ip-172-31-13-154.ec2.internal:8188/ws/v1/timeline/ 18/04/25 21:28:21 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-53-48.ec2.internal/172.31.53.48:8050 18/04/25 21:28:22 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1 18/04/25 21:28:22 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2 18/04/25 21:28:23 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1524162637175_1044 18/04/25 21:28:23 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1524162637175_1044 18/04/25 21:28:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://a.cloudxlab.com:8088/proxy/application_1524162637175_1044/ 18/04/25 21:28:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1524162637175_1044 18/04/25 21:28:32 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1524162637175_1044 running in uber mode : false 18/04/25 21:28:32 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0% 18/04/25 21:28:33 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1524162637175_1044 failed with state FAILED due to: Job setup failed : org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlExcept ion: Permission denied: user=mykishore231087, access=WRITE, inode="/mayank/output/res.txt/_temporary/1":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x

```
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:213)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1771)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1755)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:1738)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:71)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3905)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1048)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2151)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2147)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2145)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:3020)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2988)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1057)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1053)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:1053)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:1046)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1877)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.setupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter.setupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:131)  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCommitter.setupJob(OutputCommitter.java:265)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.handleJobSetup(CommitterEventHandler.java:254)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.run(CommitterEventHandler.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=mykishore231087, access=WRITE, inode=" /mayank/output/res.txt/_temporary/1":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:213)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1771)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1755)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:1738)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:71)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3905)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1048)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2151)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2147)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2145)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1427)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1358)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:558)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:252)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:3018)
... 15 more 18/04/25 21:28:33 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 2
Job Counters 
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0 18/04/25 21:28:33 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful! Streaming Command Failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

> user=mykishore231087, access=WRITE, inode="/mayank/output/res.txt/_temporary/1":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x

You created the `/mayank` directory as a hdfs superuser account. All sub directories inherit permissions of that. As the error says, folder is owned exclusively by hdfs user and is read only by everyone else

You should rather create your own user folder

```
sudo su - hdfs 
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/mykishore231087
hadoop fs -chmod -R 750 /user/mykishore231087
hadoop fs chown mykishore231087:hdfs  /user/mykishore231087
```

Edit the MapReduce code with that directory as an absolute path... `/user/mykishore231087/mayank/`

Alternatively, there is a significant difference between `output /mayank/` and `output mayank/`, the first going to the root of HDFS, the other being your user folder (where the input is being read from)

Answer (score 0):

As an hdfs admin user you need to run below command to resolve your issue.
hdfs dfs -chown -R mykishore231087:hdfs /user/mykishore231087

Problem here is your ID doesnot have valid priviliges to write data into the target direcotry. either you provide write access to the target directory in a descending  order or use above command.
inode="/mayank/output/res.txt/_temporary/1":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr**-**x

Answer (score 0):

Answer have already been done above. Just small comment. 'hadoop' command is depricated. Use 'yarn' instead as it is mentioned in your log:
"WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications. 18/04/25 21:28:18 WARN streaming.StreamJob: -file option is deprecated, please use generic option -files instead."